# PowerShell, Provision AD User Via Interactive Menu With Options

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm writing my first (very basic) PowerShell script that, basically, asks a user for some information and then uses that to provision a new AD user. Some very basic "$value = Read-Host -Prompt 'Question'" stuff going on.

However, in order to maintain our naming convention / proper spelling and capitalization for some fields (mostly Location, possible Department later down the road) I have created a menu that prompts the user to choose between a few options. Below is a screen capture of that code:

[Image 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgRxB.png)

However, the GUI (for lack of better words) does not display exactly what I'd like to see. Ideally, this would require the user to input SF, for example, with the description to read San Francisco.

[Image 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r5BF.png)

Lastly, I would like to convert the $choice variable to the actual name of the location, rather than the number that is assigned to the choice (0, 1, 2...) so that when I "Write-Host $choice" it will populate with the location name we use in AD.

[Image 03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noO6V.png)

```
# This script is my first attempt at hacking my way through New-ADUser automation using as little user input as necessary. Bear with me.

# Let's prompt the user for some information.
$name = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is their name?'
$dept = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is their department, man?'
$title = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is their title?'
$mngr = Read-Host -Prompt 'Who is their manager?'

# Let's parse that $name into a first name and last name, and then generate the user's e-mail.
$first = $name.split(" ")[0]
$last = $name.split(" ")[1]
$accountname = $first.tolower() + '.' + $last.tolower()
$email = $first.tolower() + '.' + $last.tolower() + '@mycompany.com'

# Let's prompt the user for the new hire's primary location.
$menu = "Choose Location"
$message = "What is the user's primary location?"

$sf = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "SF", "San Francisco"
$01 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "01", "San Leandro"
$02 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "02", "Mechanicsburg"
$03 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "03", "Vernon Hills"
$04 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "04", "Duluth"
$05 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "05", "Phoenix"

$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($sf, $01, $02, $03, $04, $05)

$choice = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($menu, $message, $options, 0)

switch ($choice)
{
    0 {$location = "San Francisco"}
    1 {$location = "San Leandro"}
    2 {$location = "Mechanicsburg"}
    3 {$location = "Vernon Hills"}
    4 {$location = "Duluth"}
    5 {$location = "Phoenix"}
}

Write-Host $name
Write-Host $dept
Write-Host $title
Write-Host $mngr
Write-Host $accountname
Write-Host $email
Write-Host $location
```

Comment: Can you please post your relevant code rather than just images and small snippets? Also for your question about the $choice variable, you just need to set another variable in each statement : Switch($choice) { 0 { $location = "San Francisco" } ... }

Comment: Why do you post images for textual information? And then don't even embed them?

Comment: $result = Switch($choice) { 0 {  "San Francisco"  } ... }

Comment: Hey all- I've edited the original post to include the code. As far as my third question, Owain's response solved that perfectly. Thank you.